# What does "Oh my Lanta" mean?

Tags: phrases

I've heard someone who considers himself to be a "gangster" say "Oh my Lanta". I looked up this phrase, and apparently "Mylanta" is stomach medication, and it's a replacement for "Oh my God", so you won't take the Lord's name in vain. However, this definition *really* doesn't fit. Is there another meaning for "Oh my Lanta"?

Comment: As an aside, my sense is that part of the joke is that a gangster would be concerned about "taking the lord's name in vain," given all the other nasty things his job entails.

Comment: @Mahnax You'd be amazed for what people believe themselves absolved by mincing oaths or attending church.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had originally thought it came directly from an ad campaign for Mylanta, but the more I look for it, I can't find those campaigns. I'm beginning to think they don't exist.  They did have a campaign with "My doctor said Mylanta" and I know they used "oh Mylanta" on Full House in the 80s and 90s. My guess is it's a joke that many people made, with having the 'my' built into the word it lends itself to it nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I'd never heard this phrase, but the Urban Dictionary [tells us](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=oh%20my%20lanta) that it's a way of saying "Oh my God" or "Oh my Lord" without resorting to blasphemy and the eternal damnation inherent therein.

Faced with the need to say "Oh my [something]" without taking anyone's name in vain, the next two syllables "lanta" just seem to roll off the tongue, given that Mylanta is, as you say, a well known over-the-counter antacid medication.

Comment: The oddity here is that the person that I've heard say "Oh my Lanta" would be the last person on earth to care about blasphemy.